# Write attributes to a file in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

​Hi,
I am using GetSNMP processor to connect a radio. As per the NiFi documentation, this information is written to flow file attributes not to flow file contents. So, I used AttributesToJSON processor. After that I used PutFile processor to write these attributes to a file. Files are generated but there are not attributes written there. Only "{}" is written in each of the file. Using LogAttribute processor , I can see all attributes in the log file but I want them in a separate file.
Please guide.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

SGaur,

If incoming flow file content is empty before putFile processor then it will writes empty content in local directory.

So you have to write attributes into flowfile content using ReplaceText.

For an example, You having this attributes like

`${filename}-->input.1,
${input.content.1}-->content.1,
${input.content.2}-->content.2`

comes before putFile.

Now you have to write those attributes into flow file content like below.,

In ReplaceText, Just mention replacement value to be like this-->

```
${filename},${input.content.1},${input.content.2}
```

It will replace content like below.,

```
input.1,content.1,content.2
```

Now it will write into local file using put file processor.

Hope this helpful for you.

Comment: Hi Mahendra, Thanks a lot for this help. It really worked.

Comment: Feel free to upvot/accept this to be answer.It may be helpful for someone.

Comment: Hi Mahendra, One more query. Can we access the attributes using regular expression in "Replacement Value"? I get all the attributes prefixed with "snmp$" from a radio using SNMPGet. So, rather than putting each attribute in "ReplaceText" processor, can I access all of them using something like ${'snmp$*'} . Please guide.

Comment: yes you can access using like this..${filename},${content}